# ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

By starting to build a fresh project in React Native, it is faced build failure, these are my configs:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    Memory: 627.80 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh   
Binaries:
    Node: 15.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.0.10 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman   
Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod   
SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK: Not Found   
IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild   
Languages:
    Java: 13.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python   
npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found   
npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Facebook team must fix this problem in the React Native framework, By the way, the solution is these steps:

1. Open the Xcode and find the `Build Settings` tab and then try to modify `Library search paths` under the `Search Paths` category
2. Add `${inherited}` to the first of the list ***It's important to be the first***
3. Delete the last builds and try again to build your project by using Xcode or terminal.

These solutions will fix your issue.